# create triger for custome object

Tags: custom, object

hi I am beginer with Sales Force . Please dont judge me strictly . I am trying to create trigger for customer object .

Initial data:
custom object with field: status type pickup list
 "maintanace finished",
 "open",
"in progress".

test organisation  . One of the task of this organozation has theme "Revision" and all tasks are related to custom object "transport".

The idea of trigger is following : I need to switch trigger when one of the fields status of transport ( transport is my custom object) will be changed for "maintainace finished". trigger should change status of All tasks  of the test organization with the theme "Revision" for "completed". My problem that I cant find api for all these elements of Organizations ( tasks, task's status).

```
trigger Status_completed on Transport__c (after update) 
{

  for (Transport__c  u : Trigger.new)

  {

    if ( u.Status_c  = 'Maintainace finished')

    {
"here I dont know where to find my api for tasks in orgonisation entityty  and it is fiels like theme  "
    }
  }
}
```

where to find api for organization entity tab  and it s fields like theme ?

Comment: As this is currently written, it's really difficult to understand what you're asking

Comment: now should be better .

Comment: Hi @Jack, 
We can help you out but you need to explain the relationship among the objects.
Also it will be good if youmention API names of the objects and fields.

As a suggestion, I will say you should start exploring trailhead modules where you will get the basic understanding of the code.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description I think the trigger should look like this, some of the syntax might be wrong. I wasn't sure about your lookup field from Transport__c to Tasks and the Theme field on Tasks as you didn't provide the API name;

```
   trigger Status_completed on Transport__c (before update) {

      Set<id> taskids = new Set<Id>();

      for (Transport__c  u : Trigger.new) {

        if ( u.Status__c  = 'Maintainace finished')
        {
              if(u.TaskLookupField!=null)
                taskids.add(u.TaskLookupField);
        }
      }

 List<Task> taskstoupdate = new List<Task>([Select id,Theme__c from Task where id in: taskids]);

  for(Task t : taskstoupdate){

  if(t.Theme__c=='Revision')
     t.Theme__c='Complete';    
  }

   update taskstoupdate;

}
```

Comment: Ok thanks very much . Are you sure about taskstoupdate? Because I  admire how you have done it . dint have clue before .

Comment: well you'd want to update the tasks status, right? If so you have to create a list  of tasks  that you want to update using the taskids from the lookupfield. Then you loop through your list modify the 'Theme' of your task and update the whole list

Comment: that s right . But I have question.                                                                    Error:  No such column 'Theme__c' on entity 'Task'.

Comment: Where I can see that api

Comment: you can go on setup -> task then view all the related fields